# Assigning typescript variable within if statement in Ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

In my Typescript/Ionic application, I have infinite scrolling that calls async operation like this:

When the view is first loaded, it calls `getData` with `page = 1`, and when the scroll reaches the end of the page it then calls `getNextPage`, which just increments the `page` count then directly calls `getData`. The `getData` function is as follows:

```
getData() {

  this.provider.getData(this.page).subscribe(data => {

  if(this.page == 1) {
    this.items = data;
    this.firstPageData = data;
  }
  else
    for(let d of data)
      this.items.push(d);
  });
}
```

I use `firstPageData` to quickly reload the first page when the user performs an action and returns back to the main view where sees the data items again.

However, when I use `firstPageData`, it contains all items of the scrolled pages and not only the first page! I tried to debug the code and understand what is going on there but with no luck.

Am I missing something here? Please help.

Comment: can you console `this.page` value before if statement

Comment: Just did, it increments as expected, 1, 2, 3 ..

Comment: getData() method might stacking up the each page result set, can you share getData() implementation

Comment: I mean, this.provider.getData() implementation

Comment: It is a simple function where I pass the page number as a parameter to a service url:      getData(page?:number) { return this.jsonp.get('https://myapi/getData' + '?page=' + page).map(response => response.json().results);

Comment: add few more debug statements before if statement, `console.log(this.page, data.length);`